# setting size of root in Tk tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-class

I am trying to apply first principles in terms of setting up classes here, but may be overthinking it.  Everything works great with the code below.  But I have been trying to get my class application to set the size and color of the root window.  (Note how I got the root to have a new name.)  For some reason I can't figure out geometry.  It seems clumsy to have to set the root size and color when I put in root, but it works.  I have commented out the things that I can't get to work.  Looking for some guidance.  I'm missing something but at this point I don't know what I'm missing.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
       super().__init__(master)
       self.master = master
       self.winfo_toplevel().title("Chad's title")
       #self.winfo_toplevel.geometry("500x400")
       #self.geometry("500x400")
       #self.wm_geometry(newGeometry=None)
       #wm_geometry(newGeometry=None)
       self.pack()
       self.create_widgets()
    
def create_widgets(self):
    self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
    self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
    self.hi_there.pack(side="left") 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.geometry("500x400") 
    root.configure(background="light grey") 
    app = Application(master=root) 
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your first commented-out line is trying to call `.geometry()` on the `winfo_toplevel` method itself, rather than the result of calling that method (you had it right when calling `title()`).  The other two lines are trying to call `.geometry()` on a Frame rather than a window; only the root window or a `Toplevel` support that method.

Comment: I get it now in view of your comment.  What I was leaving out on the top level were the parens.

Answer (score 0):

In view of jasonharper comment here is what works and cleans up the approach.  You must use winfo_toplevel() with the parens to get to the top/root level:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Chad's title")
        self.winfo_toplevel().geometry("500x400")
        self.winfo_toplevel().configure(background="light grey")
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
    
def create_widgets(self):
    self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
    self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
    self.hi_there.pack(side="left") 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = Application(master=root) 
    app.mainloop()
```